# Recover user profile image

Tags: images, multi-user, profiles

Android 5 has options to have [users](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2865483), so multiple people can use the device. I had my Motorola G 2 set up to use multiple users, but it now only has one profile which would be nice to recover the profile picture of:

[image]

Can this be done (without root etc as well)? I can get a very low res 90px image from screenshots but that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

`/data/system/users/0/photo.png` is the picture you're looking for. But, you cannot get that pic or even visit its parent directory without elevated privileges. [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) shell isn't enough to get it.

There is a catch here. In my Paranoid ROM (AOSP) I found that the owner is supposed to create a contact (about me) for himself. Any image used in that contact is directly user by the system as the image of the user, and hence, gets copied to that said location. This isn't the case in CM12 though.

The images provided to contacts are saved at the location `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/files/photos`. Your profile image is saved in `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/files/profile`.

Both location are inaccessible by ADB and an ordinary user. Now that I've given you ample stuff to search and research, it is up to you to choose a path: 1) root and get the stuff easily, 2) find an app that can copy the profile or contacts images in a standard format from which you can retrieve your profile image.

Comment: You can export the contacts through SMS or Bluetooth. The `.vcf` file would have encoded image into it. May be you can convert that encoding into a full-fledged image since Android can.